# Is it better to use c_str or toCharArray?

Tags: programming, c++, string

When reading/trying a [recent answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/511/42), I was surprised to see that Arduino's `String` class supports the `c_str()` method, just like the C++ `std::string` class. As expected, it appears to get a pointer to the string's contents as a null-terminated `char` array (i.e. C-style string).

However, (as far as I can see) that method is not mentioned in the official Arduino documentation. Additionally, in all example code I've seen using `String`, a different approach seems to be used. A secondary `char` buffer is setup, and then the contents of the string are copied to it using [`String::toCharArray()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray). This obviously requires double the memory, plus an O(n) copy operation.

It seems like `c_str()` should be the preferred approach. Is there some reason why `toCharArray()` is more commonly used?

Comment: Because new Arduino users don't want to branch out

Comment: Re *"that method is not mentioned in the official Arduino documentation"*: It is available now: *[c_str()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/)*

Answer (score 3):

> It seems like `c_str()` should be the preferred approach. Is there some reason why `toCharArray()` is more commonly used?

basically, I'd say it's a lack of knowledge from the people doing the codes you've seen. Definitely `c_str()` is better. Though, what I see even more often is the use of character arrays `char*` strings instead of `String` (and I plead guilty of that as well in my own codes).

And that's because the Arduino library has been built upon a messy set of C and C++ libraries and coding style. Trying to make things easier actually messed them up and complicated them more.

That's actually why we have new projects like [xpcc](http://xpcc.kreatives-chaos.com) trying to make a real and smart use of the C++ abilities in the embedded world.